# Desde donde ejecutar un FileWatcher en un projecto con spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jobs

Ya tengo funcionando un fileWatcher con WatchService, éste ejecuta una tarea cuando un archivo es agregado a una carpeta predefinida en las propiedades de la aplicacion. Sin embargo no sé cual es el mejor sitio en la aplicacion para situarlo. Actualmente lo dejé en el main, pero pienso que no deberia dejarlo alli.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class })
public class MyApplication {

    @Value("${routing.folder}")
    private static String ROUTING_FOLDER;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
        Path dir = Paths.get(ROUTING_FOLDER);
        new SepaRoutingFilesWatcher(dir).processEvents();
    }

}
```

La clase `SepaRoutingFilesWatcher` recibe la ubicacion de la carpeta y se mantiene escuchando los archivos agregados a ésta. He pensado que puedo crear un `Job` con `@EnableBatchProcessing` que lance la funcion cuando se ejecute la aplicacion, sin embargo me gustaria hacerlo de una forma mas limpia, por ejemplo desde maven.